# Success handler from http request does not call a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I did successfully a post request with angular 2 http.

The problem that I have is when I try to execute a function from success handler. The error that I get from that is: `error_handler.js:48 EXCEPTION: this.setCookie is not a function`

**My component:**

```
onSubmit(userData: any): void {
    this.user = new UserData(userData);
    this.services.getAccess(this.user).subscribe();
}
```

**My services:**

```
getAccess(user: UserData): any {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let client_id = 'fge432358768979fgwefg34f34';
    let credentials = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + client_id + '&client_secret=' + user.secretKey + '&username=' + user.email + '&password=' + user.password;
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(
        this.baseApiUrl + '/oauth/access_token',
        credentials,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    )
        .map(this.handleSuccess)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.log('error');
    swal("Oops...", 'The informations you’ve entered doesn’t match any account. ', "error");
    return Observable.throw(error);
}

handleSuccess(res: Response) {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        swal(
            {
                title: "Good job!",
                text: "You have successfully logged in.",
                timer: 2000,
                type: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false
            }
        );
        this.setCookie(res.json().access_token)
    }
}

setCookie(accessToken: string): void {
    this.cookie.setForOneHour(accessToken);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Incorrect usage of  'this'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `this` to preserve the context.

You can use

1. `.map(this.handleSuccess.bind(this))`
2. use an arrow function

   ```
   .map(data => this.handleSuccess(data))
   ```

Remember that the same applies to the `.catch()`